# Как работает getController() в FXMLLoader?

Tags: javafx

Какое значение примет controller?:

```
DialogController controller = loader.getController();
```

Comment: Ну если не убьется от сужения типов, то  DialogController

Answer (score 1):

При получении контроллера через `FXMLLoader` Вы получаете обьект, у которого:

- инициализированы поля, помеченные аннотацией `FXML`
- при инициализации всех полей (указаных выше) вызывается метод `initialize`
- вызываються соответствующие методы, которые обрабатывают соответствующие события

Последние два пункта не так важны, так как "вручную" Вы это не делаете. Главная причина получения контроллера через `FXMLLoader` это инициализированные поля.